# Creating points on street line between two intersecting streets in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-processing

I have a table which contains fields `"Street"`, `"From"`, `"To"` and `"Number of potholes"`.

- `"Street"` showing the street line where the potholes are
- `"From"` and `"To"` are street names which define part of the street where
  the potholes are
- `"Number of potholes"` is the number of points which I want to place on
  defined part of the line (between `"From"` and `"To"`).

I want to do this using QGIS.

I have an idea to download street lines from OpenStreetMap and to geocode each street and select street lines by location. I am not sure about steps after these.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: I don't quite understand what data you have in the "Street" field. Can you add a screenshot of your table?